# How do you modify the bytes in a `Hash` in Parity Substrate?

Tags: blockchain, parity-io, substrate

Given some `Hash` value that is generated within a substrate runtime, how do I modify or access the individual bytes of that hash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Hash` trait `Output` has the `AsRef` and `AsMut` traits which allows you to interact with the hash as a byteslice (`[u8]`):

```
pub trait Hash: 'static + MaybeSerializeDebug + Clone + Eq + PartialEq {
    type Output: Member + MaybeSerializeDebug + AsRef<[u8]> + AsMut<[u8]>;

    // ... removed for brevity
}
```

Using the `as_ref()` or `as_mut()` on a hash will return a slice of bytes which you can use as normal:

For example:

```
// Iterate over a hash
let hash1 = <T as system::Trait>::Hashing::hash(1);
for hash_byte in hash1.as_ref().iter() {
    // ... do something
}
```

or

```
// Add one to the first byte of a hash
let mut hash2 = <T as system::Trait>::Hashing::hash(2);
hash2.as_mut()[0] += 1;
```